# Custom sort in <v-data-table> stays in a loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a table and I do a `custom-sort` but for some reason the method stays in a loop.

```
<v-card>
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <v-toolbar-title>{{ $t('locations.list.title') }}</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
        <div>
          <v-text-field
            append-icon="fa fa-search"
            v-model="params.query"
            :label="$t('locations.labels.search')"
            :disabled="isLoading"
            single-line
            hide-details
            v-debounce:1500="search"
          ></v-text-field>
        </div>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn color="primary" :to="{ name: 'locations:create' }">
          {{ $t('locations.labels.add') }}
          <v-icon right>fa fa-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="locations"
        :page.sync="pagination.current_page"
        :items-per-page="pagination.per_page"
        :loading="isLoading"
        hide-default-footer
        :multi-sort="true"
        :custom-sort="customSort"
        @page-count="pageCount = $event"
      >
        <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
          <v-btn icon :to="{ name: 'locations:edit', params: { id: item.id } }">
            <v-icon>fa fa-edit</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon @click="requestDeleteConfirmation(item)">
            <v-icon>fa fa-trash</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
      <v-pagination
        v-model="pagination.current_page"
        :length="pagination.last_page"
        @input="search"
      ></v-pagination>
    </v-card>
```

This is my method for sorting:

```
customSort(items, index, isDesc) {
    if (index[0]) {
        const $sort = index
            .reduce((carry, item, index) => {
                const name = item;
                const order = isDesc[index] ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
                const sort = `${name}:${order}`;
                carry.push(sort);
                return carry;
            }, [])
            .join(',');
        this.params = { ...this.params, $sort };
        console.log('[carry]', $sort);
        this.search();
    } else {
        this.$delete(this.params, '$sort');
    }
    return items;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspecct there's a cyclic issue with `customSort()` triggering `search()` and `search()` triggering `customSort()`.

If not, my next guess would be that it has to do with `v-data-table`. Can you give us more information about that component? Is it from a library or did you write it yourself?

Comment: 19/5000
I defined the method because I have to send the filter information to a method that I have in an API but I don't know why the method stays in an infinite loop

i try to remove the search()